# Moving picturebox graphic with interval

Tags: c#

I'm creating graphic at picturebox from left to right side, by adding single pixel columns, with predetermined time intervals(300ms). When subsequent pixel columns exceed the picturebox width, I can't see more of them.

How to make moving picturebox window, which would allow to see the current pixel column all the time?

I'm using BASS library, code is below.

```
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    graphic = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    bool spectrum3DVoicePrint = visuals.CreateSpectrum3DVoicePrint(rHandle, graphic, pictureBox1.Bounds, Color.Navy, Color.Navy, pos, false, true);`

    graphic.Dispose();
    pos = ++;
}
```

Comment: Don't keep the code you are using to do this a secret.

Comment: @LarsTech what do you mean?

Comment: @Abbas There wasn't any code in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

you need to store each position in array.
Here is my simple code for demonstrate to draw line and move after reaches at width of picturebox. Make sure any mistake of any value of pixel,x,y,etc.. leads to wrong output.

```
    int x = -1;
    int y = 50;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    bool check = true;
    int[,] pos;
    int index = -1;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Initalize array
    pos = new int[pictureBox1.Width + 2, 2];
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphic = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        if (x < pictureBox1.Width)
        {
            index++;
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            graphic.Clear(Color.Black);
            for (int i = 0; i < pictureBox1.Width; i++)
            {
                pos[i, 1] = pos[i + 1, 1];
                graphic.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Lime, pos[i, 0], pos[i, 1], 1, 1);
            }

        }
        graphic.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Lime, x, y, 1, 1);
        pos[index, 0] = x;
        pos[index, 1] = y;
        graphic.Dispose();
        //for random dots
        //y = rnd.Next(5, 95);

        //for line
        if (check)
            y++;
        else
            y--;
        if (y == 100)
            check = false;
        if (y == 5)
            check = true;
    }
```